# Opencart information edit link missing

Tags: hyperlink, opencart

I am using opencart 1.5.6.4. I have changed template and decided to edit some pages. But I realized that a link is missing in the admin catalog menu. It is called "information" link and there is a module link instead. Module name is "auto bulk quantity discounts".

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAoSm.png)

How can I get information link on that menu?

Answer (score 0):

in opencart v2.X information is like this:

[admin url]/index.php?route=catalog/information

if it was right this url you can add this url to admin menu tpl file
*in opencart v2 is this address i think it maybe same v1.5*

```
/admin/view/template/common/menu.tpl
```

Comment: There is no menu.tpl but header.tpl in that location. But I found that a xml of that extension changes the menu. I removed xml and the link came back. But extension is not usable now.

Comment: @B.Koc could you replace again this extension? maybe it corrupted by removing something.